# How to add SD on qplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, standard-deviation

My data:

```
Store;

founder wt.Df   Viability   avg_val sd
1   A3  D   0   0   0
2   A3  D   0   0   0
3   A3  D   0   0   0
4   A3  D   0   0   0
5   A3  W   0.5 0.5 0.0673435
6   A3  W   0.5 0.5 0.0673435
7   A4  D   0.4 0.4 0.01594978
8   A4  D   0.4 0.4 0.01594978
9   A4  D   0.3 0.3 0.06475337
10  A4  D   0.3 0.3 0.06475337
11  A4  W   0.5 0.5 0.04831164
12  A4  W   0.5 0.5 0.04831164

qplot(x=wt.Df, y=avg_val, group=founder, data=Store1, geom="line", colour = factor(founder), main= "LOVE CODE, xlab = "Lines", ylab = "Average Viability", ylim=c(0,1), xlim= (c("W", "D"))) + geom_point() + labs(colour="Founders Tested") + opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle=10));
```

What I want to do, and I can't find anything online; thus, I am asking. How in the heck can I take Store$Sd and plot them to the points on my qplot graph? I am wanting the above plot with errors bars?

Comment: look up `geom_errorbar(...)`

Comment: as a side note, you might want to use theme rather than opt. opt is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x=wt.Df, y=avg_val, group=founder, data=Store1, geom="line", 
      colour = factor(founder), 
      main= "LOVE CODE", xlab = "Lines", ylab = "Average Viability", 
      ylim=c(0,1), xlim= (c("W", "D"))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(colour="Founders Tested") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=10))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=wt.Df, ymin=avg_val-sd, ymax=avg_val+sd), width=.1)
```

I'm not sure why you use lines - it just seems to create confusion.

Comment: @jihoward, I am using lines to model data for a complementation test in the future. Also can you give me a better understanding as what the aes part of the code is for?

Comment: `aes` is the so-called "aesthetic mapping". It maps variables (columns) present in your dataset (specified with `data-Store1`) to aesthetics of the geom. So here, `geom_errorbar` requires x, ymin, and ymax. The call to `aes(...)` tells ggplot to use wt.Df, avg_val-sd, and avg_val+sd for x, ymin, and ymax respectively.